# Accessing a variable from a module

Tags: python, flask

I have to make a DIY robot. In order to find out orientation of robot I am using my smartphone and [PhonePi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phonepi) app. The app is based on Flask server. The code for getting orientation is given below and I named this one as `orientation.py`:

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_sockets import Sockets

app = Flask(__name__)
sockets = Sockets(app)

@sockets.route('/orientation')
def echo_socket(ws):
    while True:
        message = ws.receive()
        raw2 = message.split(',')
        global orient1
        orient1 = float(raw2[0])
        orient2 = float(raw2[1])
        orient3 = float(raw2[2])
        print('x = ', orient1, "is", type(orient1))
        # print('y = ', orient2, "is", type(orient2))
        # print('z = ', orient3, "is", type(orient3))
        ws.send(message)


@app.route('/') 
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from gevent import pywsgi
    from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
    server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 5000), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

I have to access variable **orient1** from another script named `robot controller.py`. I tried to access variable several ways like:

```
from orientation import *
import orientation
from orientation import orient1
```

How can I access orient1 from other scripts within same folder?

Comment: `orient1` is defined in the function `echo_socket` thus it can only be accessed from within this function. One option is to define it as a global variable (then the import will work). However, most of the time global variables are not used, and you can avoid them by changing the program architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `orient1` is inside a function, so you cannot access it from any place outside this function.

What you can do is to set a general variable outside the function so you can get it by a getter function, for example:

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_sockets import Sockets

app = Flask(__name__)
sockets = Sockets(app)
orient1 = 0.0

def get_orient1():
    return orient1

@sockets.route('/orientation')
def echo_socket(ws):
    while True:
        message = ws.receive()
        raw2 = message.split(',')
        global orient1
        orient1 = float(raw2[0])
        orient2 = float(raw2[1])
        orient3 = float(raw2[2])
        print('x = ', orient1, "is", type(orient1))
        # print('y = ', orient2, "is", type(orient2))
        # print('z = ', orient3, "is", type(orient3))
        ws.send(message)


@app.route('/') 
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from gevent import pywsgi
    from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
    server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 5000), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Now, you can access it by:

```
from orientation import get_orient1
orient1 = get_orient1()
```